# Multi database support in prisma

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have 3 databases in my project. Every database has different data. But they have some relation between them. For example on the transaction database in my transaction, it has a userId stored and in the Default database User table has this user.

Now how to manage these multi-database and cross-relation between databases in **Prisma**?

I want to have the possibility to keep relation between my different databases in **Prisma**

Comment: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443#issuecomment-630679118